# TypeError: data type 'list' not understood

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, series

I have a Series object, returned by pandas `groupby`, which has elements of `numpy.ndarray` type. I would like to convert ndarrays to lists, preferably without using loops.
I tried to use `pandas.Series.astype` but I got error: `TypeError: data type 'list' not understood`. Why is that when [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) says that

> Use a numpy.dtype or Python type to cast entire pandas object to the same type.

and `list` is Python buil-id data type.

Example:

```
a = {'Id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3},
 'col': {0: 5.1, 1: 4.9, 2: 4.9}}
d = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a)
attr_unique_val = d.groupby('col')['Id'].unique()
attr_unique_val = attr_unique_val.astype('list')
```

Comment: Please attach a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the error you are facing, in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use apply and lambda, using the example you provided:

```
    a = {'Id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3},
    'col': {0: 5.1, 1: 4.9, 2: 4.9}}
    d = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a)
    attr_unique_val = d.groupby('col')['Id'].unique()
    attr_unique_val = attr_unique_val.apply(lambda x: x.tolist())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert ndarrays to list then you can use tolist() method. For example- the ndarray name is 'narr' then you can write `narr.tolist()`.

Comment: Yes, but I want to convert whole series type at one time.